# Javascript return error

Tags: javascript, return

output from chrome console

```
z = selected_sheet()
```

returns

```
5 
undefined
```

...

> z

returns

```
undefined
```

JavaScript code

```
function selected_sheet(){
        $('.sheet_radio').each( function(){
            if (this.checked == true){
                var x = 5;
                console.log(x);
                return x;
            };
        });
    };
```

So I get a correct output from console log but z does not get set to the same item that was returned from console.log.

Comment: Remember to ask a question when making a post.

Comment: So the `console.log` inside of the `each` successfully returns `5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because only one of the radio buttons can be selected at a time. I will expand on that in a minute.

So here is your code:

```
function selected_sheet(){
        $('.sheet_radio').each( function(){
            if (this.checked == true){ `Entry Point`
                var x = 5;
                console.log(x);
                return x;
            };
        });
    };
```

if the radio button is selected the control enters the  if condition `Entry Point` and hence you get the output as five,

but, if the radio button is not selected, the control doesnt go through the `Entry Point` because the if condition fails and the function returns undefined.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @user2434674 does this answer your question?

Comment: Since your querying using a class selector, it's  possible to have radio buttons with the same class. If you add **console.log(this)** before the statement  **if (this.checked == true)** you'll notice that multiple elements are logged, if the class is used multiple times.

Comment: The OP said console.log was outputting 5, therefore the inner function runs, therefore one of the radio buttons is checked.  The reason the return value is undefined is because the outer function never returns x.  It's a scoping problem.  See AnthonyS's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

This occurs because the function that is executed by **.each** only returns from the scope of that function. It does not return from **selected_sheet**.

In fact if you explicity make the function passed to each explicity return a value, you will notice that z is actually never set:

```
 function selected_sheet() {

    $('.sheet_radio').each(function() {
        return 5;
    });
    // nothing is actually being returned

 };

 z = selected_sheet(); // z is undefined
```

## Solution

One solution is to **set a default value for x in the outer scope**(or leave it undefined), and then set the value of x to the new value if a radio button is checked

```
function selected_sheet() {

    var x = 7; // set default to 7


    $('.sheet_radio').each(function() {

        if (this.checked == true) {
            x = 5; // set to new value
            console.log(x);
            return false; // stop iterating
        }

    });

    return x;
};
```

Another method is to **query with selectors** to see whether or not there are checked radio buttons:

```
function selected_sheet() {
    if($('.sheet_radio:checked').length > 0) {
       return 5;
    } else {
        return 7; // this is the default if nothing is checked
    }
}
```

Finally here is a pure JavaScript solution:

```
function selected_sheet() {
    if( document.querySelector('.sheet_radio:checked') !== null) {
      return 5;
     } else {
       return 7; // this is the default if nothing is checked
   }
}
```

and a terse version

```
function selected_sheet() {
   return document.querySelector('.sheet_radio:checked') !== null? 5 : 7;
}
```